# How to get value from Case.Account.Primary_Email__c and Case.ContactEmail from case recordID and autopopulated in To field on email page in lwc?

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

### Controller_consumerSendEmail.cls

```
public with sharing class Controller_consumerSendEmail {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void sendEmailToController(String toSend, String subject){
        try{
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toSend};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject(subject);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### ConsumerSendEmail.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import Consumer_From_Email_Address from '@salesforce/label/c.Consumer_From_Email_Address';

import sendEmailToController from '@salesforce/apex/Controller_consumerSendEmail.sendEmailToController';

import Primary_Email__c from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Account.Primary_Email__c';
import ContactEmail from '@salesforce/schema/Case.ContactEmail';
import Subject from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';

const fields = [Primary_Email__c, ContactEmail, Subject];

export default class ConsumerSendEmail extends LightningElement {
    @track email = '';
    @api recordId;
    label = {
        Consumer_From_Email_Address
    };
    
    //mail body editor 
    handleChange(e) {
        this.richtext = e.detail.value;
    }
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields
    })
    account;

    get Primary_Email__c() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, Primary_Email__c);
    }

    get ContactEmail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, ContactEmail);
    }

    get Subject() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, Subject);
    }

    handleClick() {
        const recordInput = { Primary_Email__c: this.toSend, Subject: this.subject }  //You can send parameters
        sendEmailToController(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                //If response is ok
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            }).catch(error => {
                //If there is an error on response
            })
    }
}
```

### ConsumerSendEmail.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title='Send Email' icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small">
      <lightning-input type="email" label="From" pattern=".+@example.com" value={label.Consumer_From_Email_Address} required>
      </lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="email" label="CC" pattern=".+@example.com" placeholder="username@example.com">
      </lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="email" label="To" pattern=".+@example.com" value={Primary_Email__c} required>
      </lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="text" label="Subject" value={Subject}></lightning-input>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small">
      <lightning-input-rich-text value={richtext} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-rich-text>
      <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={richtext}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
    </div>

    <div>
      <lightning-button type="submit" label="Send" variant="brand" onclick={handleClick}> </lightning-button>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I can see in your code is:-

You have referenced wrong property name in getFieldValue function. The getRecord is wired with **account** property whereas you are referencing **case** in getFieldValue.

```
@wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields
})
account;
```

and

```
   get Primary_Email__c() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, Primary_Email__c);
    }

    get ContactEmail() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, ContactEmail);
    }

    get Subject() {
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, Subject);
    }
```

To resolve, just make change in wired property as below:-

```
   @wire(getRecord, {
       recordId: "$recordId",
       fields
   })
   case;
```